# Wrap <a> elements in a <li>

Tags: jquery, html

I need to change this HTML code:

```
<div id="data-table_paginate" class="dataTables_paginate paging_full_numbers">
    <a id="data-table_first" tabindex="0" class="first paginate_button paginate_button_disabled">Primero</a>
    <a id="data-table_previous" tabindex="0" class="previous paginate_button paginate_button_disabled">Anterior</a>
    <span><a tabindex="0" class="paginate_active">1</a><a tabindex="0" class="paginate_button">2</a></span>
    <a id="data-table_next" tabindex="0" class="next paginate_button">Siguiente</a>
    <a id="data-table_last" tabindex="0" class="last paginate_button">Último</a>
</div>
```

To this one:

```
<ul id="data-table_paginate" class="dataTables_paginate paging_full_numbers">
    <li><a id="data-table_first" tabindex="0" class="first paginate_button paginate_button_disabled">Primero</a></li>
    <li><a id="data-table_previous" tabindex="0" class="previous paginate_button paginate_button_disabled">Anterior</a></li>
    <li><a tabindex="0" class="paginate_active">1</a></li>
    <li><a tabindex="0" class="paginate_button">2</a></li>
    <li><a id="data-table_next" tabindex="0" class="next paginate_button">Siguiente</a></li>
    <li><a id="data-table_last" tabindex="0" class="last paginate_button">Último</a></li>
</ul>
```

As you may see it's only change `div` element for a `ul` and wrap every `<a>` inside the `div` in a `li` (also get out the `span` and change for `li` instead). I'm not a jQuery expert but I'm pretty sure it's easy, can any give me a hand here?

**PS:** The code is dynamic so maybe it have only one a but maybe it will have several

Comment: Do you have any code presently that we can see how this is generated? Or are you looking to fix it using a 1 liner?

Comment: `I'm not a jQuery expert but I'm pretty sure it's easy`, so why not take a stab at it and let us know where you're getting stuck. Take a look at all the [DOM Manipulation](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/) functions in jQuery to start with.

Comment: You want to generate it and the change it client side with JQuery?

Comment: Sounds like you might make use of [`.wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/).

Comment: @KyleMuir it's generated trough PHP but don't worries about that because the result will be always the same meaning the first, latest, next and previous `<a>` will exists the only that will change is the middle one because could be one page or two or three or more, this is what I said before

Comment: @pandavenger no, I just want to change in client side, is just for styling purpose

Comment: @MattBurland sure I'm reading and looking for, trying to do by myself but don't get it until now, for that I ask for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very simple using jQuery:

```
$('div#data-table_paginate a').wrap('<li>');
```

Noticing that you have `<span>` in your midst then you need to use the `.children()` without a selector.

If you want to do it with plain javascript below is a working solution for 1 level of children and it's heavily refactorable.

```
var nodes = document.querySelector('#data-table_paginate');
var newHTML = "<ul>";
for(var i = 0; i < nodes.children.length; i++) {
    if(nodes.children[i].children.length > 0) {
        for(var j = 0; j < nodes.children[i].children.length; j++) {
            newHTML += "<li>"+ nodes.children[i].children[j].innerHTML +"</li>";
        }    
    } else {
        newHTML+="<li>"+nodes.children[i].innerHTML+"</li>";
    }
}
newHTML += "</ul>";
nodes.innerHTML = newHTML;
```

Made a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/qtFcm/2/)

I've updated my solution to fit your specs.
Note: Using jQuery hinders a lot of the nestled code you need.

Comment: it works for the rest of elements but not for the one inside the `span`, notice in the code I want to covert that I remove the span complety and separate the `<a>` inside. Testing your code I get this `<li><a tabindex="0" class="paginate_active">1</a><a tabindex="0" class="paginate_button">2</a></li>` and I need this `<li><a tabindex="0" class="paginate_active">1</a></li><li><a tabindex="0" class="paginate_button">2</a></li>`

Comment: Also how to add ul and remove the main container `div`? (`div id="data-table_paginate"`)?

Comment: fine, it doesn't remove the `a` elements but I can't click any link? This is rare, why?

Comment: Because you haven't supplied a `href=""` making the `a` not a link but a normal anchor.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) function:

```
$(function() {
    $('#data-table_paginate a').wrap('li');
});
```

This will find all anchors in the `data-table_paginate` div and wrap them in an `li` element.